# Sound leaks from speaker even when headphones are inserted

Tags: windows-xp, audio, dell-optiplex

I've a Dell Optiplex 960 (which I presume has a speaker inside the tower). This speaker is normally in use whenever I play music (lets call this "**tower speaker**"), and when I insert my headphones in the 3.5mm jack (of the tower), the tower speaker stops and the music is played through the headphones (an obvious thing to happen). But sometimes, the tower speaker starts playing the music even when the headphones are inserted! So, the music is played through both of them! This gets quite embarrassing.

So, my question is - Is there a way to turn off this "tower speaker"?

EDIT : I'm using Windows XP

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Windows XP.

Comment: A screwdriver through the speaker cone should do it.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a hardware issue. may be your stereo jack connector on your tower speaker got weak to hold headphone stereo jack and connection is happening  "as is".

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to turn off the speaker in the bios. If not, you can disconnect the speaker.

Under Windows you may be able go to Control Panel... Sound and disable that speaker.

Answer (score 0):

If you look on the bottom right-hand side of your Taskbar, where the clock is, you should see a little megaphone icon representing your audio controls.  Right-click on this and go to Playback Devices.  There, you should see all of the devices you have installed that are capable of playing sound.  Just right-click on the one labeled Internal Speakers and choose to Disable it, and voila!